# Installing SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my computer. I want to install Service Pack 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2. Do I need to select upgrade option or new installation during installation of service pack or remove current installation and install SQL Server again.

I am trying to select "new installation or add new features" on first page of installation and then  selecting current instance on next page but It is giving some error like registry value invalid.

Comment: Server Fault - or super user or put some more info in please....

Comment: What edition of SQL Server is it, Express or other? Where did you get the download file?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're running the wrong file.

Download one of the files from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727 and then run that. It shouldn't prompt you for "new installation or add new features", it should prompt you for which instance you want to apply the service pack to.

Answer (score 0):

You are running the `SQL server setup` wizard which is not what you need. To patch your instance after you have installed SQL server, get the respective patch from Microsoft, which is a single file, and then run this file on your server.

I believe @Rob has provided a link from where you can get your respective patch. Download this file, and run it (run as administrator if required), and follow the installation instructions.